# Why has my try catch block stopped working? (Dart, Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

When the user logs in for the first time I want to create a new account. If there is already an account I just want to log the user in. So want I try to create an account first and if the error is "EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE" I'll just log the user in.

This used to work just fine until I upgraded my flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.86). Now the app is always crashing even tough the error takes place in a try block. Has this something to do with the upgrade of flutter?

Thank you for your answers

**Error Message**

> PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account., null, null))

**Code Snippet**

```
if (await isValid(email, password, shortSchoolURL)) {
      try {
        AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);

        FirebaseUser user = result.user;
        return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

        //
      } catch (registerError) {
        if (registerError.code == "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE") {
          try {
            AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: email, password: password);
            FirebaseUser user = result.user;
            return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
          }
...
```

**Flutter Doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.86, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021 darwin-x64, locale de)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to be on "master"?  Are you planning on debugging the SDK for them? :)

Please switch back to "stable".

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I changed my channel to stable and ran flutter upgrade to get the latest stable flutter version. Now can't run even run the app 
'Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.'

Comment: "flutter clean" in your repos?

Comment: I ran "flutter clean" and I'm still getting the same error message. before my the error message there is this warning "warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')"

Comment: Might need to fix that then.

Comment: Any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: Let me google that for you.  Let's see.  Oh here, first hit: https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2020/07/20/xcode-12-drops-support-for-ios-8-fix-for-cocoapods/

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. Thank you